# En Git-flow, ¿cómo puedo crear una feature, trabajar en ella y subir los cambios a la rama develop?

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit, git-flow

He creado un proyecto y he inicializado git, estoy intentando seguir Git-flow para tener una rama master, una rama develop y dentro de esta rama develop crear las features o hotfix correspondientes.

Para esto realizo lo siguiente:

1. Creo la rama "develop" y me mueva a ella

   ```
   git checkout -b develop
   ```
2. Creo la rama feature_100 y me mueve a ella

   ```
   git checkout -b feature_100
   ```
3. Hago un git branch y veo las 3 ramas  , con un asterisco veo la rama donde estoy actualmente

   ```
   $ git branch
   develop
   * feature_100
   master
   ```
4. Realizo los commit necesarios

   ```
   git commit -m "Add User model"
   ```
5. Incorporo los cambios de la feature a la rama develop

   ```
   git merge --no-ff feature_100
   ```

Resultado por consola :

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Y si vuelvo a hacer un "git branch" tengo este resultado por consola

```
$ git branch
develop
* feature_100
master
```

Mi problema como podeis ver es cómo cerrar esta "feature" y poder crear otra.

Comment: ¿Sabes que puedes utilizar [`git-flow`](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)? Te permite decir cosas como `git flow feature start blabla` y acabar con un `git flow feature finish blabla`

Comment: Lo de `git merge --no-ff feature_100`, ¿desde qué rama lo haces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sé que no respondo al caso particular, pues ya está resuelto. Sin embargo, quizá este aporte ayude. Para los impacientes: [pueden mirar el link del manual git-flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)

---

Para contextualizar el tema rápidamente:

Mientras que git es un gestor de versionado, Git-flow es un protocolo para administración de ramas sobre git.

Git-flow también puede ser usado dentro de consola tal como git si se instala en el proyecto (.git).

Tal como está tu proyecto sería inicializar Git-flow:

```
$ git-flow init
```

Y gestionar tus tipos de ramas (`feature | hotfix | release`) dependiendo de lo que desees (`start | finish | publish | pull`) así:

```
$ git-flow [feature | hotfix | release] [start | finish | publish | pull] <nombre_rama>
```

El [link](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) te ofrece mas información.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que el paso 5 no ha hecho nada en realidad, puesto que entiendo que la ejecutaste mientras la rama activa era `feature_100`, con lo que has mezclado la rama `feature_100` consigo misma (y obviamente no hay nada que hacer para ese caso).

Lo correcto sería cambiar a la rama `develop` (`git checkout develop`) y desde ella hacer el merge en cuestión `git merge --no-ff feature_100`).

Una vez has hecho el merge, si la rama `feature_100` no va a usarse más, puedes eliminarla con `git branch -d feature_100`. Eso no borra ningún commit del historial (`git log` desde la rama `develop` aún te mostrará los commits de aquella rama y el merge), simplemente elimina el nombre (referencia) a esa rama, lo que elimina "ruido" de la lista que te da `git branch`.